# How to translate SQL into Lambda for use in MS Entity Framework with Repository pattern usage

Tags: entity-framework, lambda, repository-pattern

For example take these two tables:

**Company**

```
CompanyID | Name | Address | ...
```

**Employee**

```
EmployeeID | Name | Function | CompanyID | ...
```

where a Company has several Employees.

When we want to retrieve the Company and Employee data for a certain Employee, this simple SQL statement will do the job:

```
SELECT e.name as employeename, c.name as companyname
FROM Company c
INNER JOIN Employee e
ON c.CompanyID = e.CompanyID
where e.EmployeeID=3
```

Now, the question is how to translate this SQL statement into a 'lambda' construct. We have modelled the tables as objects in the MS Entity Framework where we also defined the relationship between the tables (.edmx file). 
Also important to mention is that we use the 'Repository' pattern.

The closest I can get is something like this:

```
List<Company> tmp = _companyRepository.GetAll().Where                 
  (
     c.Employee.Any
     (
       e => e.FKEngineerID == engineerId && e.DbId == jobId      
     )
   ).ToList();
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This should do, assuming your repositories are returning IQueryables of the types

```
var list = (from c in _companyRepository.GetAll()
            join e in _employeeRepository.GetAll() on c.CompanyId equals e.CompanyId
            where e.FKEngineerID == engineerId && e.DbId == jobId      
            select new 
            { 
                    EmployeeName = e.name, 
                    CompanyName = c.name
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks. However, in our model we already defined the relationship between the two tables (objects) so why is an JOIN needed here?

Comment: Well you could do with just using the companies and do a SelectMany to get the employees with company names. But that should generate about the same sql (a part from the where condition) you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are constraining the query to a single employee (`e.Employee=3`) why don't you start with employees.

Also, your sql query return a custom set of columns, one column from the employee table and the other column from company table. To reflect that, you need a custom projection at the ef side.

```
var result = _employeeRepository.GetAll()
    .Where( e => e.DbId == 3 ) // this corresponds to your e.EmployeeID = 3
    .Select( e => new {
        employeename = e.EmployeeName,
        companyname  = e.Company.CompanyName
    } ) // this does the custom projection
    .FirstOrDefault(); // since you want a single entry

if ( result != null ) {
    // result is a value of anonymous type with
    // two properties, employeename and companyname
}
```

Comment: correction: I do not want to constraint to a single employee; for example, the sql could be something like this:                                                                                     SELECT e.name as employeename, c.name as companyname
FROM Company c
INNER JOIN Employee e
ON c.CompanyID = e.CompanyID
where e.Employee.gender = 'Female'

Comment: so, in that case there will be more occurences of the Employee. How is this to be translated into lambda?

Comment: Same but without the FirstOrDefault and you just correct the clause in Where.